# Unable to compare date variable in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

**I am having issue **

**while comparing date variable in if clause, because i am getting one date variable value is "$'2014-04-19\r'"  and another one is 2014-04-19.**

how i come to know the value of variable is this

by set -x property in my shell script

value of variable  in if condition has shown me in command line is below  -

*+ [ $'2014-04-19\r' == 2014-04-19 ]*

so how can i compare because in simple text format both variable looks same, and i want to be true that condition.
can we remove $' and \r' from that variable...

Comment: Where did `$'2014-04-19\r'` come from? And can you show the part of your code you're talking about rather than just a trace output?

Comment: i have the input file which has data look like -  + echo $'65572|42|33115|0|P|598||2014-04-09|2014-04-19\r'
 and i have to do operation into last column so i am doing cut on it, so i am having that value from last column..

Comment: can we remove those extra things apart from date format.. any how ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare using `[[ and ]]` in BASH like this:

```
s=$'2014-04-19\r'

[[ "$s" == '2014-04-19'? ]] && echo "similar"
```

OR more precisely:

```
[[ "$s" == '2014-04-19'$'\r' ]] && echo "similar"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like :

```
sed 's/\'\\r\'//g' < your_input_file > your_output_file
```

It will replace the unwanted string with the space.